# What are concrete examples for class G up to 14500?

Tags: usa, airspace

It is said that there are some places where class G goes up to 14500 and then class E starts. However, I find they all overplayed with some special use airspace by looking at NorCal and SoCal Sectionals. Can anyone point me to some non-trivial 14500' Class G places? It is best to see some civilian airport within it.

Comment: Are you only looking for examples from the USA?

Comment: @J.Hougaard Yes, I am for answers in US in this question.

Comment: @falstro: In US, Class E may start from surface, 700, 1200, 14500, and sometimes a customized AGL.

Comment: Ah, you're right there's also the jagged blue line. Forgot about that one. There's some funky E space over Nevada. :)

Comment: @falstro "in the lower 50"? Usually, the "lower 48" refers to the contiguous 48 states, excluding AK & HI. Was that a typo, or is that an aviation reference that I'm totally unfamiliar with?

Comment: @FreeMan typo. sorry. Too many for my fingers and toes... ;)

Comment: @falstro - just checking. It could be that we'd annexed Canada and Mexico, and I just hadn't noticed... :)

Comment: @FreeMan UK maybe? ;)

Comment: Lots of G to 14.5k in Alaska and Canada. Not much left in CONUS due to the proliferation of radar here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It can be difficult to find these areas on a VFR sectional (there are very few of them anyway), but on an (FAA NACO) IFR en route chart [they're shaded brown](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/#ifr-airspace-information), so they stand out very clearly from the background. Here are a few grouped together in South Dakota.

IFR chart:

[image]

VFR chart:

[image]

At the western end of those areas there's a public airport, [Bison Municipal (6V5)](http://airnav.com/airport/6V5):

[image]

Comment: There's so few of them it's a wonder they even bother to define it as 14500

Comment: The highest peak in continental US is Mount Whitney at 14,505'. Class E starts at 14,500. Probably not a coincidence.

Comment: @TomMcW This has changed substantially in the last 10-15 years. When I started flying there were lots of areas that I was familiar with that were Class E starting at 14,500. Now all those areas are gone, and only a few examples remain in the lower 48. I expect to see the trend continue, with a chance that current definitions may indeed become obsolete and superseded.

Comment: @Pondlife All of your examples are now gone.

Answer (score 4):

There are two left.  Big bend national park in Texas and New Mexico near Cato MOA

Comment: @Stephen, examples? Scanning the continental US on skyvector, I only see those two. The areas mentioned in other answers are no longer G-to-145. There are some areas of higher G charted along the Mexican and Canadian borders, and some beginning a little ways out to sea, but the two Tim mentioned are the only ones I can find actually in the US. I don't even see any left in Alaska anymore.

Comment: @randomhead What the …!?  There was a ton all over the Southwest and Alaska last time I looked, and I didn’t think it was that long ago. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example [jewett mesa](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=33.461&lon=-111.728&zoom=10&api_key=763xxE1MJHyhr48DlAP2qQ). Inside this polygonal shape is class Golf extending up to 14500 MSL:

[image]

Comment: Looks like is has been chopped in half since the answer, making Jewett Mesa now 1200ft below class G

Comment: Search for Airport (C54) for to find the Smitty MOA on skyvector.com. https://skyvector.com/?ll=34.14658987217066,-108.2852325395162&chart=301&zoom=3

Answer (score 2):

L41 is another example for the case where the class E begins from 14500 and there is a public airport on the surface in the region.

### [image]

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [Big Bend Area of Texas](https://skyvector.com/?ll=29.563184842750402,-102.93969726085854&chart=301&zoom=5). Large chunk of what your are looking for on the sectional chart in that area.