# Why is it assumed on sectionals that the area outside of a 700 AGL Class E (Echo) transition area is Class E starting at 1,200 AGL?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, aeronautical-charts

In this Bold Method article (http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/airspace/class-g-airspace/) it is stated that anything beyond the hard lines of this examples **1,200 ft AGL Class E** (blue) transition area is **Class G** (Golf).

So far so good.

[image: Class G Airspace]

However, further down in the article, it is stated that beyond the hard lines of the magenta **700 ft AGL Class E** transition area that the airspace is **Class G** until **1,200 ft AGL** at which point it turns into **Class E** again (think the blue Class E area that exists above this entire area).

[image: Class G Airspace]

Why is it assumed that outside the **700 ft AGL Class E** transition area there lies **1,200 ft AGL Class E**? It surely isn't represented in the screenshot. Couldn't it just as well be **Class G** until **14,500 ft AGL**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the legend on the side of a VFR chart. (You can get them for free at https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/ )

*Class E exists at 1200' AGL unless otherwise designated as shown above.*

[image]

Comment: I don't know why I didn't bother to re-read the legend, thank you for the answer. This legend however indicates that the magenta Class E doesn't necessarily have to be against a 1,200 ft. AGL Class E. It is possible to be against Class G. Do you know of any examples where this situation can be found?

Comment: Even though I’ve read the legend hundreds of times, I missed it as well until you asked the question.

Comment: There are actually only a handful of places in the us where the 14,500 Class G exists. Check out http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29523/8730

Comment: If you are bored sometime, try to figure out all of the different floors and ceilings of Class G around Death Valley and the Saline MOA.

Comment: So does anyone know any examples where the 700' Class E floor actually does laterally abut against class G airspace, as depicted as a possibility on the chart legend in this answer?